# Subscript text in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using the following code to write the table. Now I wish to
add subscript text after the table text. How can it be achieved?

My code has:

```
  oCell = document.createElement("TD");
  oCell.innerHTML = data;
  oRow.appendChild(oCell);
```

How do I add a subscript text followed by the data?

Comment: Please make clear what you mean. HTML table syntax can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may mean this:

```
oCell = document.createElement("TD");
oSub = document.createElement("sub");
oSub.innerHTML = data;
oCell.appendChild(oSub);
oRow.appendChild(oCell);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to append another element to the `td` element:

```
var newElem = document.createElement("sub");
newElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode("foobar"));
oCell.appendChild(newElem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just carry on with the innerHTML you're using:

```
oCell.innerHTML = data+'<br /><sub>'+subText+'</sub>';
```

Or even

```
oCell.innerHTML = data+'<br />'+subText.sub();
```

for some JavaScript 1.0, retro good?

Answer (score 0):

> oCell.innerHTML = data;

If 'data' can contain '<' or '&' characters, you've just done a blunder. Instead, use createTextNode to put plain text into HTML:

```
oCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
oCell.appendChild(document.createElement('sub')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(subdata));
```